Multi-Threading KafkaItemReader using SynchronizedItemStreamReader in Spring Batch
I'm comparing multiple options regarding to KafkaConsumer in SpringBatch.
With the example from spring batch project, I wrote simple code which runs KafkaItemReader as it is intended to use - single threaded.
Then I wanted to try it in multi-threaded scenario as well.
I'm aware of that both ItemReader and KafkaConsumer are not thread-safe and I saw this issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/760) regarding the same question I have.
I tried the option with the SynchronizedItemStreamReader first.
After I created simple topic items (just numbers from 1 to 10000), I tried to run my batch job.
Here is my code

    @Bean
    public Job multiThreadJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step multiThreadedStep1) {
        return new JobBuilder("comparisonJobMultiThreaded", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(multiThreadedJobExecutionListener())
                .start(multiThreadedStep1)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step multiThreadedStep1(JobRepository jobRepository, DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(6);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Multi-No.");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();

        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .<String, String>chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor)
                .reader(multiThreadedItemReader())
                .processor(new ItemProcessor<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String process(String item) throws Exception {
                        recordHandler.processRecord(item);
                        progressBar.stepTo(recordsConsumed.incrementAndGet());
                        return item;
                    }
                })
                .writer(fileItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<String> multiThreadedItemReader() {
        Integer[] partitions = IntStream.range(0, numPartitions).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);

        KafkaItemReader<String, String> kafkaItemReader = new KafkaItemReader<>(appProperties, topic, partitions);
        kafkaItemReader.setPollTimeout(Duration.of(500, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));

        return new SynchronizedItemStreamReaderBuilder<String>()
                .delegate(kafkaItemReader)
                .build();
    }

But it only created two different kafka consumer client (distinguished by clientId) and throws
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access. currentThread(name: Multi-No.6, id: 34) otherThread(id: 29)

I kind of hoped that SynchronizedItemStreamReader does the magic with multi-threading :)
appearently not..
What am I doing wrong?
Appreciate your help!
